# Dialog Box creates additional document on edit (once saved)

Tags: xpages

This sounds like a strange query - however I am using a dialog control in an xPage from the extension library (running 9.0.1 FP3, using web browser) and am finding that when I edit a document, another blank document is created (a doc with only the form set).  The edit works correctly, just I get this additional document.

I have checked the following:

- there is only 1 data source for the xpage (the data source is set on a control).
- I have tried the data properties of ignoreRequestParms and the variety of concurrency options to no avail.
- I do have an agent running on the PostSaveDocument event, however have removed this and the same error still occurs.

There is lots of code so I have not posted the code here - if you would like some components posted then let me know.

Appreciate any assistance on finding (and eliminating) the cause.

A

Comment: Is your data source defined in dialog, or at the page level, or ...?

Comment: Hi @FrantisekKossuth, it is defines at the root level of the custom control. (I had thought it was defined at the root level of the panel within the dialog box but was incorrect).  Should it be defined one or the other way?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some code that reloads the page, or use "data context" which is known for executing multiple times. Try to set the document data source context to "request"

Comment: Hi @Thomas, I am pretty sure there are no reloads happening, and am not sure where a 'data context' would be set?  I have checked under properties (data \ dataContext) and there is nothing there. I have changed the scope to 'request' under properties \ data \ dominoDocument but that did not affect anything.

Comment: have a look in the extlib sample database included in the download package, you should be able find a sample there that do not create an empty doc in edit

Comment: You need to isolate where the problem is, create a new database or a new xpage and add  your dialog and any other needed components into that and see if you get the same result. if it still is not working add your code here and we can help you troubleshoot it

Answer (score 0):

Hard without any code but another cause might be the type of action button I assume you have to save the document. Is it a type "button" or "submit"? If the latter then the save action is performed regardless you have SSJS code/simple actions to do so. If you have additional actions defined then the save action is executed twice.

Comment: Hi @Oliver - there is no save, I have only got the submit button.  If I change a field on the document then it saves fine, I just get another blank document.

Answer (score 0):

Some guidelines to troubleshoot your problem.

First of all - double check in sources view of your elements that you DO NOT define duplicate data sources (at different places with the same name).

I suppose you can view the extra document in Notes client. Look at the properties panel and compare all four timestamps: Created/Modified combined with overall/in this file.

Are overall/in this file dates the same? Good, that means no replication is involved.

Are created and modified dates the same? Good, that means document is created and saved once and at the some moment. Now - use your application but do it slowly, one step per 5/10 seconds and notice what you do and when. Look at the time stamp and update your question: what exact moment does create your document: open page, open dialog, close page, some button...

If created/modified times differ, look at $Revisions field and you will see exact moments the documents was saved - and how many times.